# Storing/Reusing intermediate results on a java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of A , To execute filtering I need to map A to B. But once the filtering logic is done I still need A for further operations, So My question is would it be at all possible to achieve this? One approach I can think of is storing both A and B into a third type, so I have both available, while processing the stream, but not sure that is elegant and wondering if here is a better way.Or am I trying to fit a square peg in a round hole by using streams.

```
List<A> a;
List<B> b = a.stream().map(i -> load(i)).filter(need A here in addition to b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can always pass two things wrapped into a `Pair`, `array`, `List` for example:

```
a.stream().map(i -> List.of(load(i), i)) // List#of is java-9, replace with Pair or array
          .filter(x -> x[0]...)
          .filter(y -> /* y is List here */)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no elegant solution here, but you could do filtering within mapping:

```
.map(a -> {
    B b = load(a);
    return filter(a, b) ? b : null;
})
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

You don't need to create wrappers around the stream elements. The `load` method will be executed only once in case it is an expensive operation.

`null` is the default invalid value, it should be replaced if `null` is allowed or it can be returned from `load`.

Comment: Or `.flatMap(a -> { B b = load(a); return filter(a, b)? Stream.of(b): null; })`

Comment: @Holger, yes, it's a better one

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous class on the fly (or any appropriate existing class to represent a pair or alike) as:

```
a.stream().map(e -> new Object() { A a=e; B b=load(e); })
          .filter(x -> /*any code using x.a and x.b */)
```

Be aware that some IDEs doesn't accept this while it is perfect valid Java 8 code.

Comment: it took me a while to figure out that line is anonymous class creation with 2 fields (though I like these things and do sometimes)

Comment: `...x.a...x.b...` is not a valid syntax, could you put it into a comment?